# Submit the dynamic select box value to show the mutlipolygon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here i'm trying to show the multipolygon according to the selection of area in openlayers 3 , e.g. when i select landcover on first select box then on the second box it will shows corresponding value like water bodies , built up area etc. 
 Actually stuck in between of that how to submit the value to show the result on map .

Here's my code
This the Html code.

```
<div class="popup">
 <tr><select id="a1_title"></select></div></tr>
 <tr><select id="a2_title"></select></div></tr>
        <!-- Button (Double) -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cancel"></label>
        <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success submit">OK</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="map" class="map"><div>
```

This the javascript through which i'm calling value of php page

```
 // JavaScript Document
        $(document).ready(function(){
               $.getJSON("php/drpdwn.php", success = function(data){
                    var items="";
                    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                        // RETAIN JSON KEY AS OPTION VALUE, JSON VALUE AS OPTION TEXT                items +="<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>" + data[i].name+"</option>";
                    }
                    $("#a1_title").append(items); 
                    $("#a1_title").change();
                });
               $("#a1_title").change(function(){

                  // OBTAIN SELECTED VALUE
                  var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").text();

                   if( selectedValue == "Landuse/landcover") {

                      $.getJSON("php/lulc_db.php",success = function(data){              
                          var items="";
                          for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){

                              items+="<option value='"+data[i]+"'>" + data[i] +"</option>";
                          }
                          // REMOVE PREVIOUS ITEMS
                          var myNode = document.getElementById("a2_title");
                          while (myNode.firstChild) {
                              myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
                          }
                          // ADD NEW ITEMS
                          $("#a2_title").append(items);  
                      });
                      $("#a2_title").change(function(){
                    //the main problem start from here 
//this the only one which is not working                                 
                        var selectedtext = $(this).find(":selected").text();
                         if( selectedValue == "Built Up") {
                             alert("k");
                        $('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
           $.getJSON("php/geojson.php?layer="+ $(this).text(),success = function(data){
    console.log(data);
            });
        });          }
                         });

                  }
                  else if( selectedValue == "Soil") {         

                      $.getJSON("php/soil_db.php",success = function(data){              
                          var items="";
                          for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){

                              items+="<option value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>";

                          }
                          // REMOVE PREVIOUS ITEMS
                          var myNode = document.getElementById("a2_title");
                          while (myNode.firstChild) {
                              myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
                          }
                          // ADD NEW ITEMS
                          $("#a2_title").append(items);       
                      });
                                }  

                });

              });
```

And this the php page from which i wanted to show the value

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["layer"]))
   {
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$pass = "admin"; 
$db = "Querybuilderdb"; 
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 
$sql = "SELECT gid, level_1 , st_asgeojson(geom) AS geojson FROM  pachgaon_lulc where level_1='{$layer}'  ";
$rs = pg_query($con, $sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n";
    exit;
}
# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($rs)) {

    $properties = $row;
    # Remove geojson and geometry fields from properties
    unset($properties['geojson']);
    $feature = array(
         'type' => 'Feature',
         'id' => $row['gid'],
         'properties' => array(
          'name' => $row['level_1']
          ),

         'geometry' => json_decode($row['geojson']), 
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson);
}
?>
```

My most important question how to submit the result on click of "ok" button of matching the condition of both select boxes because i know the way i'm doing its not working at all.I'm very knew in javascript please help me out of this from problem.

Comment: You want to submit the values of both selection boxes to geojson.php when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: @budwiser  No...i'm not trying to inserting the value into php page. i'm trying to submit the value of php page onto map. on the bases of selection of box

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120124/insert-dynamic-select-box-value-in-mysql-database-and-show-data-submitted-messag/44123272#44123272

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("php/drpdwn.php", success = function(data){
    var items = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      // RETAIN JSON KEY AS OPTION VALUE, JSON VALUE AS OPTION TEXT                items +="<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>" + data[i].name+"</option>";
    }

    $("#a1_title").html(items);
    $("#a1_title").change();
  });

  $("#a1_title").change(function(){
    // OBTAIN SELECTED VALUE
    var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").text();

    if(selectedValue == "Landuse/landcover"){
      $.getJSON("php/lulc_db.php", success = function(data){
        var items = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          items += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

        /* update options */
        $("#a2_title").html(items);
      });
    }else if(selectedValue == "Soil"){
      $.getJSON("php/soil_db.php", success = function(data){
        var items = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

          items += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";

        }

        /* update options */
        $("#a2_title").html(items);
      });
    }
  });

  $("#a2_title").change(function(){
    //the main problem start from here 
    //this the only one which is not working
    var selectedtext = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    if(selectedtext == "Built Up"){
      alert("k");
      $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
        $.getJSON("php/geojson.php?layer=" + $(this).text(), success = function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Problem is here:

```
/* setting selected option value to `selectedtext` */ 
var selectedtext = $(this).find(":selected").text();
/* trying to get previously set value from `selectedValue` but assigned to `selectedtext` */
if( selectedValue == "Built Up") {
```

And in your code you are binding change event multiple times

```
if( selectedValue == "Landuse/landcover") {
...
  $("#a2_title").change(function(){ /* binding change event every time if condition is evaluated to true */
```

in if condition

and one more thing the way of removing options from select element you can simply use replace html using `$().html()` or just call `$().remove()`;

Comment: No this is not working . And the most important it should be place inside that if else loop because for each and every change of value i need to call the another page. can't change the place. Is there something i'm doing wrong to submit the result because when trying to check it from alert its even going into second nested loop of first if condition

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of it? or if it's live somewhere you can share url as well

Comment: there is no url but i'm trying to creating a plunker of it ..its not done yet but u can check it https://plnkr.co/edit/QM85kRkd4JpxeCUA6Yan?p=preview

Comment: Not possible to debug it here sorry;

Comment: Right now i'm able to receive the page ..can you please how to match the value of php page from the sec box ...u can check the plunker on multiploygon.geojson this the result i'm receiving from that page .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107727/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-ads).

Comment: you forgot to include `script.js` in html file;